# SignalR .NET Core: Failed writing message. Aborting connection. Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'inputType')

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serialization, signalr

I'm using SignalR to stream some realtime data. I can connect with my js client perfectly, however as soon as I invoke a method I receive the error below, only when I'm using the debug logs for signalR (otherwise it just throws `Error: Invocation canceled due to the underlying connection being closed.` on invoke). If I put breakpoints in the hub where the method is called he goes through it, but somehow I still get this hidden error.

```
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher[1]
      Received hub invocation: InvocationMessage { InvocationId: "0", Target: "WatchSimulations", Arguments: [ System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Guid] ], StreamIds: [  ] }.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher: Debug: Received hub invocation: InvocationMessage { InvocationId: "0", Target: "WatchSimulations", Arguments: [ System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Guid] ], StreamIds: [  ] }.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionContext[6]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionContext: Debug: Failed writing message. Aborting connection.

System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'inputType')
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Object value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol.WriteCompletionMessage(CompletionMessage message, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol.WriteMessageCore(HubMessage message, IBufferWriter`1 stream)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol.WriteMessage(HubMessage message, IBufferWriter`1 output)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionContext.WriteCore(HubMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      Failed writing message. Aborting connection.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionHandler: Debug: OnConnectedAsync ending.
      System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'inputType')
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.Transports.WebSocketsTransport: Debug: Waiting for the client to close the socket.
         at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Object value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions options)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol.WriteCompletionMessage(CompletionMessage message, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol.WriteMessageCore(HubMessage message, IBufferWriter`1 stream)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol.WriteMessage(HubMessage message, IBufferWriter`1 output)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionContext.WriteCore(HubMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionHandler[6]
      OnConnectedAsync ending.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.Transports.WebSocketsTransport[7]
      Waiting for the client to close the socket.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.Transports.WebSocketsTransport[2]
      Socket closed.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.Transports.WebSocketsTransport: Debug: Socket closed.
```

Hub:

```
    [Authorize]
    public class ProgressHub : Hub<IProgressHub>
    {
        public Task WatchSimulations(List<Guid> simulationUids)
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task>();
            simulationUids.ForEach(id =>
            {
                tasks.Add(
                    Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, id.ToString())
                );
            });
            return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }
    }
```

I'm using .NET Core 3.1 and @microsoft/signalr 5.0.0.

Anyone recognizes this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error can occur if you're referencing System.Text.Json 5.0 from a 3.1 project. 3.1.11 will contain a fix for that. For now, you can either avoid updating System.Text.Json, upgrade your app to net5.0, or switch to using Newtonsoft.Json instead of System.Text.Json.

Comment: Switching to Newtonsoft.Json worked! Thanks!

Comment: May I ask how, exactly, you go about switching to Newtonsoft? the system.text call is made in the signalr library itself, which I'm not certain how to access.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=dotnet#switch-to-newtonsoftjson

Comment: This doesn't work for me. After updating to 3.1.12, or even adding newstonsoft.Json support nothing changes. Still getting System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'inputType'). I'm really desperate now.. @Brennan? Any ideas?